# In Pytest, does conftest.py at the root level get overridden by conftests deeper in the tree?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pytest

Our current project has a project tree with a conftest.py at the root level of the tests like below:

```
Tests
   test_folder_1
   test_folder_2
   conftest.py
```

This root level **conftest.py** imports most of our fixtures at session and class levels. But in **test_folder_1**, we have another **conftest.py** that we want to override some of those class level fixtures and turn them function-scoped.

I was under the impression that this would work and has been working, but now I'm getting errors with some of these: `You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'new_primary_contact' with a 'class' scoped request object`

If this is not how to override fixtures from conftest.py, is there another way? It could be another error, but I really want to know if conftest.py's further in the tree actually override high level ones. Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Here is an minimal example of my code:

Root level **conftest.py**:

```
from automation.Fixtures.ClassScope import config, api_client, new_related_contact, \
    new_primary_contact, auto_clean_contacts_helper as contacts_helper, create_contact_payload, document_helper
```

In my lower level test, in **root/feature_1** I have something like this in a **conftest.py**:

```
from automation.Fixtures.FunctionScope import new_related_contact, \
    new_primary_contact, auto_clean_contacts_helper as contacts_helper, create_contact_payload, document_helper
```

I was just wanting to override certain fixtures, so my function level tests would not use class scope.

Here is a test example using them in **root/feature_1/Tests**:

```
class TestDeleteRelatedContactWorkflow:
    def test__remove_related_contact(self, authenticated_chrome_driver, config, new_primary_contact, new_related_contact, new_contact_proposal, contacts_helper):
        primary_contact_name = new_primary_contact["display_name"]
        related_contact_name = new_related_contact["display_name"]
        related_contact_id = new_related_contact["ContactId"]
        document_id = new_contact_document["id"]

        web_nav = WebNavigation(authenticated_chrome_driver, config)
        web_nav.navigate_to_document_view_page(document_id)
        ...
        response = contacts_helper.delete_contact(related_contact_id)
        assert response["IsSuccess"] is True, f'Deletion of contact "{related_contact_name}" not successful.'
        assert response["StatusCode"] == 200, 'Status code should == 200 when deleting contact.'
```

The test fails before it logs in and after the webdriver/browser initiates (names changed to protect code)

```
test setup failed
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'new_primary_contact' with a 'class' scoped request object, involved factories
root/Fixtures/ClassScope/class_scoped_document_fixtures.py:19:  def new_document_payload(config, new_primary_contact)
root/Fixtures/FunctionScope/function_scoped_contacts_fixtures.py:85:  def new_primary_contact(contacts_helper, create_contact_payload)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the fixture, the override fixture, and the test using the override?

Comment: @KyleParsons I added the code example up above. Thank you!

Comment: So the issue is definitely that the more immediate `conftest.py` _is_ shadowing the root.  You  have a root fixture `new_document_payload` that relies on the fixture named `new_primary_contact`.  `new_document_payload` is class-scoped while `new_primary_contact` is the lower down, function-scoped fixture, which is the issue.  Either `new_document_payload` is a prerequisite of some fixture you _are_ using, or `pytest` has some need to instantiate all fixtures even if they're not being used.  In any case you might need to translate every fixture to the function scope.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, class-scoped fixtures cannot rely on function-scoped fixtures.

Comment: Totally clear what's wrong with our code from your description. Thank you so much @KyleParsons! I think between your answer and the answer below, I know exactly what to do to fix this and also prevent all our scope headaches in the future (We keep running into it for now obvious reasons). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add conftest.py to ROOT folder, only if I was 100% sure all my tests are using all imported fixtures there, otherwise you are just slowing down automation execution which is critical.

I have tested the following:

```
Tests
   conftest.py
   test_folder_1
        conftest.py
   test_folder_2
```

Both conftest.py files had fixture function with the same name.
in test_folder_1/conftest.py - I have set scope="function" and returned different value compared to the same fixture in Tests/conftest.py (which had scope="class").

In a test under test_folder_1,
I was able to use the updated fixture from test_folder_1/conftest.py.
I am not able to apply this fixture on a class, as the scope changed.

Comment: Thank you! I think you and Kyle Parsons both hit on different but related flaws in how our codebase is using conftests.py. I think the answer here is to refactor the root conftest and only keep the 100% used fixtures there (Like config, which is used in every test) and then filter imports down in the test structure as needed, whether that be in conftests or not. That will give us more execution speed, and help up stop having so many scope conflicts. This wasn't the first time we've run into this!

That sounds like a good strategy to you, right?

Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Sounds pretty good to me. In my company's project, we create fixtures in scope=function (or "session" tbf) -> pass it to the class fixture -> then we apply the class fixture to the relevant TestClasses.

If it's not clear and you need an example, let me know.